# body styles not showing through gutters in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css

I have a layout I've created using CSS Grid. My `body` element has a different background color than the actual sections of the grid. I would like this color to show through the "gutters" I have created in my grid using `margin`. I've linked a fiddle of this problem:

```
body {
  background: #f00;
  margin: 0;
}

#page {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "navigation content" "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 15% 75% 10%;
  background: #fff;
}

#page>* {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#page>header {
  grid-area: header;
}

#page>nav {
  grid-area: navigation;
}

#page>main {
  grid-area: content;
}

#page>footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<section id="page">
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <h1>Navigation</h1>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </footer>
</section>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yf1ft0pt/)

Comment: If you remove `background: #fff;` on `#page` and uncomment the CSS you commented out, doesn't that fix it?

Comment: no, what i want is the red body background to show through the gutters of the grid

Comment: Wouldn't that be this https://jsfiddle.net/yf1ft0pt/1/?

Comment: Or, if you want to go with the code posted here, add the `background:#fff` to the `#page>*` after you remove it from the `#page`

Comment: @j08691 yep, you were right. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve this using the `Outline` property:

```
#page > * {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: 5px solid #f00;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making the entire background of the `#page` section white. To have the red show, the white needs to apply only to the interior of the children of `#page`. Move the `background` style from `#page` to `#page > *`, like so:

```
#page {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-areas: "header header"
                       "navigation content"
                       "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 15% 75% 10%;
}

#page > * {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}
```